# WYSIWYG for displaying sql query

Tags: php, wysiwyg

i am looking for a wysiwyg to embed in my web page. the thing is, the wysiwyg am looking for should be table based wth functionality for printing and editing the displayed data.

Data that will be displayed to the wysiwyg will be from a mysql query.

i use php.

Answer (score 1):

Those are RTE's but don't come with a highlight code syntax..

Maybe this article helps you to get started? It introduces the Text_Highlighter package from PEAR.

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/highlight-source-code-php

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) or [FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) are good places to start for WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: do they support displaying/editing mysql query data in table form?

Comment: i don't know exactly what you mean with "mysql query data". Is maybe phpmyadmin what you want? http://www.phpmyadmin.net/